# iOS: UIButton strange border issue when cornerRadius added

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift2, border, cornerradius

iOS 9 - Swift 2

I have added a cornerRadius on a button. That makes a strange gray border on the non-cornered part of the button (see image).
As soon as I remove cornerRadius, the border disappears.

Strange thing is that this gray border is visible only on device, NOT visible in the simulator.

Code is pretty simple and this is not happening on other buttons:

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.defaultAppColor()
button.layer.cornerRadius = 20
button.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Image of button:
[image: button border]

Has anybody experienced this before?

Comment: haven't got such issue before, try adding user defined runtime attribute layer.borderWidth to 0

Comment: @AjinkyaPatil I have tried. With borderWidth 0, nothing happens. And with borderWidth > 0, a border is just drawn on top like it is supposed to and covers the strange gray lines, so I have fixed it like that so far (using background color as border color)

Comment: ok if nothing works you can continue using this workaround to wrap grey borders

Comment: I don't think that you need `button.layer.masksToBounds = true`. I know that when *I* give buttons corner radii I never write that and it always works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find the solution to the problem, and it doesn't seem persistent. I think it has something to do with auto layout and the way the corner radius is applied.

Anyhow, I solved it by adding a border to the button with the same color as the background color.

Hope that helps other in same situation.

Comment: Did you end up finding a more effective solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
button.clipsToBounds = true
```

Use this . And I hope your problem would be solved

Comment: Remove this line  and then try. button.layer.masksToBounds = true

Comment: @ArunKumar I already have done that as you can see in the code in the question.